# Map on a Pandas DataFrame Column cointaining lists

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas, spacy

I am doing some Textmining and therfor I need to lemmatize my documents after tokenization. So I have written a function that uses the python nlp libary spacy to convert my tokenized text column into a lemmatized text column. Actually I supposed that it woulb be easy and straight forward but for some reason it does not work. My DataFrame looks like:

[image: my DataFrame][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nstvC.png)

As mentioned before I have written a function for lemmatizing lists of strings using spacy:

```
de = spacy.load('de')
def lemmatizer(x):
   return [de(unicode(y))[0].lemma_ for y in x]
```

When I use it on a simple list of strings, it works fine:

[image: simple list of strings][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pT0Ce.png)

Problems are occuring when I try to use it on my filtered column using map.

```
removed_pd['test'] = removed_pd['filtered'].map(lambda x : lemmatizer(x))
```

[image: error message][3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yx1bU.png)

I don't know why because my lemmatizer function operates on lists and the column 'filtered' contains lists.

[image: column type]][4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v50gb.png)

And using other list functions like len works fine:

```
removed_pd['test'] = removed_pd['filtered'].map(lambda x : len(x))
```

[image: using len function][5](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7rEkn.png)

Comment: How working `print(removed_pd['filtered'].map(lemmatizer))` or `removed_pd['filtered'].apply(lemmatizer)` ?

Comment: @jezrael Absolutely, using apply can solve the problem

Comment: @SRingne - And if use `map` if failed? I am curious

Comment: apply is producing the same error

Answer (score 0):

I used textblob-de python package.
[pypi link](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/textblob-de)

```
from textblob_de.lemmatizers import PatternParserLemmatizer


def lemmatize_text(text):
    _lemmatizer = PatternParserLemmatizer()
    return [_lemmatizer.lemmatize(w)[0][0] for w in text]

removed_pd['test'] = removed_pd['filtered'].apply(lemmatize_text)
```

Comment: Unfortunaly not, because I have german texts and nltk lemmatizer does only support enlgish words.

Comment: It seems ther's issue in your `de` function. Can you add that as your question?

Comment: @VeyselKo Check the new edited solution, i used different library for german lemmatization textblob-de

Comment: Using your textblob_de generates: **ValueError: need more than 1 value to unpack**      ---> 62                 w, tag, phrase, role, lemma = t.split('/')